# Can table of content be parsed using some formal grammar?

Tags: parsing, grammar

A table of content can look like:

```
Preface 
Table of Content
Chapter 1 ...
1.1 ...
1.1.1 ...
1.1.2 ....
1.2 ...
Summary
Exercises
Chapter 2 ...
...
Appendix ...
A ...
A.1 ...
A.2 ...
B ...
References 
Index
```

Its logical structure is a tree of multiple levels:

```
Preface 
Table of Content
Chapter 1 ...
    1.1 ...
        1.1.1 ...
        1.1.2 ....
    1.2 ...
    Summary
    Exercises
Chapter 2 ...
...
Appendix ...
    A ...
        A.1 ...
        A.2 ...
    B ...
References 
Index
```

1. I wonder if parsing a table of content into a tree is a parsing
   problem according to some grammar (e.g. regular grammar,
   context-free grammar, or some other grammars)?
2. If yes, how can we specify the grammar of a table of content?
3. Can your parsing method deal with ambiguous case e.g.

   ```
   Preface 
   Table of Content
   Chapter 1 ...
   1.1 ...
   1.1.1 ...
   1.1.2 ....
   1.2 ...
   Summary
   Exercises
   Chapter 2 ...
   2.1.1 ...
   2.1.2 ...
   Appendix ...
   A ...
   A.1 ...
   A.2 ...
   B ...
   References 
   Index
   ```

   where `2.1.1 ...` is a one level lower than `Chapter 2 ...`, while
   `1.1.1 ...` is two levels lower than `Chapter 1`?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to verify that the section numbers match up with the chapters they're under?

Comment: I can need. But would like to know both cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is neither complete nor tested, but it should give you the general idea.

```
start
  = outermost_line+

outermost_line
  = no_dot_word description? '\n' one_dot_line*

one_dot_line
  = one_dot_word description? '\n' two_dot_line* | two_dot_line

two_dot_line
  = two_dot_word description? '\n' three_dot_line* | three_dot_line
```

The `outermost_line` contains any number of `one_dot_lines` within it.  The way you handle your skipping straight to two dot lines is the `| two_dot_line` that can pass through to the next layer.  Verifying that the chapter numbers match up with the section numbers I wouldn't do in the parser, but the next layer up.

Comment: thanks. what kind of grammar is it?

Comment: @Tim This would be a context-free grammar.

Comment: @eigenchris: Would it be possible to use some packages in Python?

Comment: @Tim I have never used a parser-generator before, but [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) might be worth looking into.